# Package *selinput* | Recommended for LaTeX Beginners?

Tags: input-encodings

- I travel this site often to get new ideas or to see what new packages / solution are becoming state-of-the-art or are considered to be "best practice".
- By accident, I saw an old (2012) post of the KOMA class author (https://komascript.de/faqdokumentzweispaltigabstracteinspaltig) in which *Markus Kohm* is using the `selinput` package (never heard of it before, or I forgot).
- **Question:** Is this an approach that I should show in a LaTeX introduction? Do you (high rep users) also use this for your own packages?

> **[selinput](https://ctan.org/pkg/selinput) – Semi-automatic detection of input encoding** This pack­age se­lects the in­put en­cod­ing by spec­i­fy­ing pairs of
>   in­put char­ac­ters and their glyph names.

Comment: AFAIK Markus has used this package only in MWEs on the KOMA-Script website (or other pages) in former times. And I am really sure that he also recommends the usage of utf-8.

Comment: The package makes sense if one is writing up a quick MWE in a forum, because one does not have to worry about encodings and explain how they work for an otherwise unrelated question. It might also be useful in case one copy-and-pastes the same code across machines with different encoding setups, but I guess nowadays almost everyone is using UTF-8 (or at least they should) and so that use case is not really important any more. For proper documents (especially written by beginners) UTF-8 (with or without `inputenc` following the April 2018 release) is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @esdd Thanks for your assessment. I did not want to discredit Markus by any means ;).

Comment: Also `selinput` seems to be a German thing: The forum search on TeX.SX turns up 70 hits for `selinput`, but TeXwelt.de has 150 hits, goLaTeX around 500 hits. I guess that could be the result of the habit of a few very active German helpers. You may also be interested in the German answer https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/5546/wie-stelle-ich-die-codierung-meines-dokumentes-am-besten-ein/5566 Of course some English speakers don't have problems with non-US-ASCII chars at all, so that could also explain it.

Comment: I wouldn’t count as high-rep, but I agree with everybody else that UTF-8 is the way to go for new documents. In particular, though, UTF-8 is what all code listings on TeX.SX are stored in, so you definitely want to use it when copying to or pasting from here. Fortunately, as David Carlisle answered, it recently became the default encoding in TeX Live.

Comment: @moewe quite possibly due to the "interesting" placement of  `ß` in the T1 font encoding which means in German getting the input encoding declaration wrong is more likely to bite you than in say English or French,

Comment: @Davislor ".... in LaTeX" not ".... TeX Live"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Even better! I stand corrected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Time has moved on and I wouldn't recommend this package to beginners, or use it in my documents.

Given the author, it is of course technically good at solving the problem it tries to solve but...

The problem of deciding which legacy file encoding a file is in should (in 2018) be solved by not using legacy file encodings, not by having a clever auto-detection.

Most operating systems and text editors should by now be defaulting to UTF-8 and (since this year's release) LaTeX does not need you to specify `inputenc` at all if you are using UTF-8.

[image]

So a package to detect if you are using latin1 or mac roman encoding or utf-8 is interesting if you are trying to process an archive of legacy documents, but not something to highlight in a beginner tutorial.

Comment: I've answered but I might change my mind and delete and vote to close as "opinion-based" it's very marginally on topic for the site

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of the "marginally on topic"...but I still tried :).

Comment: `(since this year's release) LaTeX does not need you to specify inputenc at all if you are using UTF-8.` --> can you point me to a reference for that?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner latex news of course:-) https://www.latex-project.org/news/2018/04/10/issue28-of-latex2e-news-released/

Comment: I added a screenshot - hope that's ok!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner yes although it over-emphases the latex change, I'd have said the same last year, that beginners should all be using utf-8 so selinput not that relevant, even though then you would need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the document.

Comment: Is `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` completely benign? If so, I should probably keep including it unless the listing depends on something like `fontspec`. There are still a lot of installations that use older versions of PDFTeX.

Comment: @Davislor yes definitely. I'd use that on any shared source for a year or two yet.... In some ways changing the default is more a statement of intent (pre-answering this question:-) rather than a default that you can rely on using any time soon. (although you mention fontspec, never use inputenc with luatex or xetex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, that’s what I thought. To clarify one thing: I’ve been using `inputenc` in my answers here **except** when the code sample needs XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX anyway, for example because it depends on `fontspec`.

Comment: This got much more attention than I anticipated.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner whether or not you load fontspec you should never use inputenc with xelatex of lualatex, although unless it's a really old release it doesn't actually do  harm: if it is used with utf8 it just makes a warning that it is doing nothing and if it is used with any other option  it gives an error.